# Sending data between UITextField and UITableView on different View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uitableview

I have searched quite a bit for this but I am not coming up with anything, the only thing I can kind of think of that may work would be NSMutableDictionary.
Anyways, to the point, for example, on one view controller lets call it InputViewController.
So on InputViewController you have two UITextFields, lets say "User name" and "password".
When the user hits save on InputView, it links to "TableView" Table view displays the username and password in one place. Say a subcategory named "My user name and Password."
And when they click it it'll show the username and password they entered in "Username"and "Password"
Thank you so much. Anything would help!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing out on the "M" part of MVC. You've got your views and controllers, but you're trying to make an app without any model objects, which is why you're struggling.

Create a subclass of NSObject called User. Give it string properties called "username" and "password". Make it into a singleton by adding the following method:

```
+ (User *)sharedUser
{
    static User *sharedUser = nil;
    if (sharedUser == nil)
    {
        sharedUser = [[User alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedUser;
}
```

Now you can access it from anywhere in your program by importing User.h and saying

```
User *user = [User sharedUser];
```

So you can set the username/password in your first view controller by saying

```
User *user = [User sharedUser];
user.username = theUsername;
user.password = thePassword;
```

And retrieve them in your second view controller by saying

```
User *user = [User sharedUser];
NSString *username = user.username;
```

etc...

Comment: Nick's right :)  A good read on MVC is what the project needs.  It will make your project infinitely easier to organize and maintain in the future.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I am going to take it back up and try that I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

When the user hits "Save" on you InputViewController, take the values from the UITextFields and store them in an NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary* userCreds = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: username, @"username", password, @"password", nil];
```

Then pass that NSDictionary to your TableViewController (a class that you've made that extends UITableViewController) via some method like `setUserCredentials: (NSDictionary*) userCreds`.  Then you can store the dictionary there, and retrieve the values when populating your table view's data.  (let me know if you need pointers on how to get the data from the dictionary to displaying in the TableView.  I don't know how you want your TableView to look, so you'll have to provide some more info there.)